# How to pass a parameter to the template I'm extending, and use it inside a template?

Tags: java, templates, playframework

I'm using a master template for all our emails. I would like this master template to use an ID field that is passed along from the concrete template:

**some-email.html**

```
#{set 'emailId'}1{/set}
#{extends 'app/views/Mails/mail-main.html' /}
...
```

**mail-main.html** (this is the master template)

```
// Here, I would like to use the emailId parameter inside another template.
// Specifically, a link I'm rendering
<a href="@@{Foo.bar(emailId)}`>Link text</a>
```

But, if I understand correctly, that's not how the `set` and `get` template works - they only allow me to embed the object in the template text in the template that uses `get`, not to pass it along to other templates.

Is there a simple way to do what I seek?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can just write the following, in **mail-main.html**:

```html
<a href="@@Foo.bar(get('emailId'))">Link text</a>
```

Comment: Actually, the `get(emailId)` that you originally wrote didn't do it - I edited your answer with the correct snippet.